# Group by but not a function like mean or sum, instead return all strings as a vector

Tags: r

Here is a data frame:

```
     label    category
     orange   fruit
     apple    fruit
     carrot   vegetable
     leek     vegetable
     dog      animal
     cat      animal
```

I would like to group by category and have a vector or labels for each in a list format:

```
fruit = c(orange, apple)
vegetable = c(carrot, leek)
animal = c(dog, cat)
```

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: `split(df$label, df$category)`

Comment: Try `unstack(df1, label~category)`

Comment: Thanks both, will accept as an answer if you like @Sotos. Thanks also akrun, I used Sotos' solution since it's a list format result